# java spring MappingJacksonJsonView not doing toString on mongodb ObjectId

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, jackson

I am using the MappingJacksonJsonView in my SpringMVC application to render JSON from my controllers. I want the ObjectId from my object to render as .toString but instead it serializes the ObjectId into its parts. It works just fine in my Velocity/JSP pages:

```
Velocity:
    $thing.id
Produces:
    4f1d77bb3a13870ff0783c25


Json:
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '/things/show/4f1d77bb3a13870ff0783c25',
             dataType: 'json',
             success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
             }
         });
    </script>
Produces:
    thing: {id:{time:1327331259000, new:false, machine:974358287, timeSecond:1327331259, inc:-260555739},…}
        id: {time:1327331259000, new:false, machine:974358287, timeSecond:1327331259, inc:-260555739}
            inc: -260555739
            machine: 974358287
            new: false
            time: 1327331259000
            timeSecond: 1327331259
        name: "Stack Overflow"


XML:
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '/things/show/4f1d77bb3a13870ff0783c25',
             dataType: 'xml',
             success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
             }
         });
    </script>
Produces:
    <com.place.model.Thing>
        <id>
            <__time>1327331259</__time>
            <__machine>974358287</__machine>
            <__inc>-260555739</__inc>
            <__new>false</__new>
        </id>
        <name>Stack Overflow</name>
    </com.place.model.Thing>
```

Is there a way to stop MappingJacksonJsonView from getting that much information out of the ObjectId? I just want the .toString() method, not all the details.

Thanks.

Adding the Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setOrder(1);
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setFavorPathExtension(true);
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setFavorParameter(true);
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setIgnoreAcceptHeader(false);
        Map<String, String> mediaTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mediaTypes.put("json", "application/x-json");
        mediaTypes.put("json", "text/json");
        mediaTypes.put("json", "text/x-json");
        mediaTypes.put("json", "application/json");
        mediaTypes.put("xml", "text/xml");
        mediaTypes.put("xml", "application/xml");
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
        List<View> defaultViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        defaultViews.add(xmlView());
        defaultViews.add(jsonView());
        contentNegotiatingViewResolver.setDefaultViews(defaultViews);
        return contentNegotiatingViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "xStreamMarshaller")
    public XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller() {
        return new XStreamMarshaller();
    }

    @Bean(name = "xmlView")
    public MarshallingView xmlView() {
        MarshallingView marshallingView = new MarshallingView(xStreamMarshaller());
        marshallingView.setContentType("application/xml");
        return marshallingView;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jsonView")
    public MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView() {
        MappingJacksonJsonView mappingJacksonJsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        mappingJacksonJsonView.setContentType("application/json");
        return mappingJacksonJsonView;
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = { "/things" })
public class ThingController {

    @Autowired
    private ThingRepository thingRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/show/{thingId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable ObjectId thingId, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("thing", thingRepository.findOne(thingId));
        return "things/show";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous answer did the trick, but it was ugly and not well thought out - a clear workaround to actually fixing the problem.

The real issue is that [`ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) deserializes into its component parts. `MappingJacksonJsonView` sees [`ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) for what it is, an object, and goes to work on it. The deserialized fields being seen in the JSON are the fields that make up an [`ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html). To stop the serialization/deserialization of such an object, you have to configure a `CustomObjectMapper` that extends [`ObjectMapper`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html).

Here is the `CustomeObjectMapper`:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        CustomSerializerFactory sf = new CustomSerializerFactory();
        sf.addSpecificMapping(ObjectId.class, new ObjectIdSerializer());
        this.setSerializerFactory(sf);
    }
}
```

Here is the `ObjectIdSerializer` that the `CustomObjectMapper` uses:

```
public class ObjectIdSerializer extends SerializerBase<ObjectId> {

    protected ObjectIdSerializer(Class<ObjectId> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public ObjectIdSerializer() {
        this(ObjectId.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ObjectId value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        jgen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
}
```

And here is what needs to change in your `@Configuration`-annotated class:

```
@Bean(name = "jsonView")
public MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView() {
    final MappingJacksonJsonView mappingJacksonJsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setContentType("application/json");
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setObjectMapper(new CustomObjectMapper());
    return mappingJacksonJsonView;
}
```

You are basically telling Jackson how to serialize/deserialize this particular object. Works like a charm.

Comment: There is no such need of custom serializer. Simply **ToStringSerializer** can be used.

Comment: @KapilBhagchandani the use of a custom serializer becomes necessary when you want to serialize an array of object ids. But then the implementation would have to be a little different in order to support arrays.

Answer (score 3):

By default Jackson provides the serialization of Object received. ObjectId returns the Object therefor its attributes are visible after conversion to JSON. You need to specify the type of serialization required, Here in this case it is string. **Thing** entity class which is used to create **ThingRepository** will look like this to get this done:

```
public class Thing {
    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using= ToStringSerializer.class)
    ObjectId id;

    String name;
}
```

Here make a note of added anotation **@JsonSerialize(using= ToStringSerializer.class)** which instructs to serialize the ObjectID to String.

Comment: If you work in Kotlin, it must be `@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer::class)`

Comment: I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using autowired instance of the auto configured mapper in Spring Boot, you can just add this customizer bean:

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return builder -> builder.serializerByType(ObjectId.class, ToStringSerializer.instance);
}
```

Relevant imports:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
```

And then this will reflect anywhere the autowired mapper is used, for example:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public String getJsonForMongoCommand(Document document) {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mongoTemplate.executeCommand(document));
    }
}
```

Or in this specific case (untested, might be unnecessary):

```java
@Bean(name = "jsonView")
public MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    final MappingJacksonJsonView mappingJacksonJsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setContentType("application/json");
    mappingJacksonJsonView.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return mappingJacksonJsonView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to just make the getId() method return a String. It was the only way to make Jackson stop serializing the ObjectId.

```
public String getId() {
    if (id != null) {
        return id.toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setId(ObjectId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

setId() still has to be ObjectId so Mongo (and its driver) can set the ID correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answers, if you face a scenario where you also need to serialize an array of ObjectId, you could create a custom serializer with the following logic:

```java
public class ObjectIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(final Object value, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (value instanceof Collection) {
            final Collection<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final Object id : ((Collection<?>) value)) {
                ids.add(ObjectId.class.cast(id).toString());
            }
            jgen.writeObject(ids);
        } else {
            jgen.writeString(ObjectId.class.cast(value).toString());
        }
    }
}
```